# How to fix SIGSEGV in C in this situation?

Tags: c, struct, binary, malloc, segmentation-fault

I've looked around everywhere to try figure out how to fix SIGSEGV and have only seen that it's due to dangling pointers or not allocating enough memory. I think that this keeps giving the error because of something to do with the malloc function which i still don't exactly understand.

Currently I have tried filling the malloc function with larger or bigger numbers and the same with the array of structures and continuously get the SIGSEGV error when compiling so treat the 999999's as a filler if you will.

My understanding of the code is that in the main function after opening a binary file is that it would read individually, each struct member into a struct array which has been created called "arr". This array of structs would then be sorted with the qsort function. the f pointer would then rewind to the first block of memory and then write out the sorted array of structures out to a binary file and finally the memory would be freed. Am i close at all to what i'd like to achieve with this?

```
    while(!feof(f)){
    struct variables *arr[999999]; //create array of structs??
    *arr = malloc(999999); //allocate required memory to the array of structs??
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.monkey), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.apple), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.shield), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.car), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.house), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.pool), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.person), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.spade), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.traffic), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.egg), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.envelope), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.hair), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.speaker), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.sword), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.tower), 1, f);
    fread(&arr, sizeof(c.phone), 1, f);
    qsort(&arr, 16, sizeof(c), compare);
    rewind(f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.monkey), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.apple), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.shield), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.car), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.house), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.pool), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.person), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.spade), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.traffic), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.egg), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.envelope), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.hair), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.speaker), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.sword), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.tower), 1, f);
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(c.phone), 1, f);
    free(*arr);
```

Comment: In case of fread(&arr... you are giving address of pointer. What do you expect here?

Comment: sorry, I was changing a few of parameters to see if it would solve any of my problems and left it like that however just leaving it as (arr...) does not solve it either.

Comment: You fix a SIGSEGV by removing the bug that causes it. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues

1. You are allocating stuff in the heap first, and then in the stack?
2. You're allocating space for `pointers to struct variables` instead of space for `struct variables`.
3. Why `999999`?

#### Allocating structs in the stack

This will allocate an array of 999999 pointers to `struct variables`.

```
struct variables *arr[999999];
```

What you probably want is an array of `struct variables`

```
struct variables arr[999999];
```

A pointer takes 8 bytes (in the most common architecture).

#### Allocating structs in the heap

Alternatively you can allocate stuff in the heap

```
struct variables *arr = (struct variables *) malloc(999999);
```

This is useful if you want the memory to be available after you leave the function; or to be resized (see `realloc`). The downside is that you're now responsible to free it when you don't need it anymore (see `free`).